# What error codes should kernel modules use on Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am writing a kernel module that will return error codes should something go wrong. My problem is that these are the same codes will be returned by `init_module`. I currently have only one situation in which my kernel module will fail and the error code would have been `-1` which is interpreted as there being a problem with permissions. This means it would be indistinguishable from a case of the process actually not having the permission to load modules. So, which codes should I use? A number lower than the lowest error defined in the kernel errno headers?

Comment: If EPERM describes the problem with loading your module well, you may return this error code. `This means it would be indistinguishable from a case of the process actually not having the permission to load modules.` - The process doesn't have permission to load *concrete* module. This is what error code means.

Comment: Check *include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h*. Any of those you may use. Read **carefully** POSIX documentation on real application of those error codes. Not all of them, besides nice naming, are applicable to most situations.

Answer (score 0):

As Tsyvarev said, if the error number *describes the problem with loading your module well, you may* (and indeed should) *return this error code* (negated, from `init_module()`) usually. But you should make exceptions from this rule for errors used in `insmod` or documented for the system call `init_module`, because e. g. `return -ENOENT` from the `init_module()` function makes `insmod` misleadingly output `Unknown symbol in module`. Instead of those errors better use less mistakable error codes as EIDRM, EUCLEAN or ECANCELED.